# How do I write regex to validate EIN numbers?

Tags: c#, regex, match

I want to validate that a string follows this format (using regex):

```
valid: 123456789     //9 digits
valid: 12-1234567    // 2 digits + dash + 7 digits
```

**Here's an example, how I would use it:**

```
var r = new Regex("^[1-9]\d?-\d{7}$");
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("1-2-3"));
```

I have the regex for the format with dash, but can't figure how to include the non-dash format???

Comment: Future --- http://www.regexr.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^\\d{2}-?\\d{7}$");
```

This will accept the two formats you want: 2 digits then an optional dash and 7 numbers.

Answer (score 4):

```
^ \d{9} | \d{2} - \d{7} $
```

Remove the spaces, they are there for readability.